# mouse touchpad doesnt work after sleep

Tags: touchpad

Hey, i just bought a new laptop, th eproblem is that when i put my pc on sleep then after it wakes up the mouse touch pad is all messed up and doesnt work so i have to restart my laptop. Is this some problem with laptop or some other?

Comment: I would suggest that http://superuser.com/ is a better place to ask this question.

Comment: Laptop problems are mass produced and thus show up in Google.  Can you pass the make and model?

Comment: try putting the laptop to sleep manually and waking it up again. see https://superuser.com/questions/1652274/hp-laptop-touchpad-randomly-stops-working/1764926#1764926

Answer (score -1):

I would be willing to bet it's a software problem. If you just bought the laptop, call tech support and see what they can do. Unless you give us all the specifics of your machine, they're going to know a lot more about the problem than we will.