# HP laptop touchpad randomly stops working

Tags: touchpad, hp-pavilion

My HP laptop's touchpad randomly becomes unresponsive, but when it is, it still moves the cursor with an external mouse. Because of this, I had to force shutdown my laptop because I couldn't do a graceful shutdown (no USB mouse). How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to replace the keyboard or the part that holds the touchpad. Either that or open the laptop and see if the connection ribbon needs re=seating.

Comment: The author could also use an external mouse, they know using one, allows mouse functions to return. The touchpad likely should be replaced

Comment: @Ramhound author stated they can use a usb mouse to move the cursor.

Comment: @Moab - That is the reason I suggested they use an external mouse.  I am going under the assumption the author does not have the technical knowledge to reseat the cable.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem with my HP laptop. After it resumes from Sleep or Hibernate, sometimes the touchpad wouldn't work properly.

The solution that worked for me was to put it back into Sleep using the Windows start menu. Then log back in. Then the touchpad worked properly again.